# How to make grid of album covers QT python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

Currently i am trying to do it with QTableWidget but i cant seem to adjust the width of the table to the parent element, so when resizing is made, the columns need to increase. QtableWidget is placed in QTabWidget in the first tab. For more info, it is a music player like that:
[image]

You can see that in the `Tab 1` grid is going out of parent bounds horizontally. Vertically is not a problem but i will disable the horizontal scroll and i need the count of columns to fit the current size of the tab WITHOUT cell resizing.Cells must have the same size always except if regulated by the slider below the tab view. Tabs are needed to fit album covers so they will be square later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way to do this would be with a `QGraphicsView`.  You would create a `QGraphicScene` the same width as the view and place all the album covers accordingly.  Based on the size of each image and the padding between them, you can compute how many you can fit on a single line.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: Can you please show me some example code for multiple images. I am having a hard time implementing that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem kinda solved. I replaced the TableWidget with list widget in `IconMode` view mode.